# map does not return even if queue is empty

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

When my queue is empty, the map method does not return.

For the script to complete, I could use `treahdpool.map_async` or `tasks.get(block=False)`.
But I'd like to understand why it does not unblock `threadpool.map()` when it's done with the queue.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from queue import Queue

def threadworker(tasks):
    while True:
        # try:
        #     func, args, kargs = tasks.get(block=False)
        # except Empty:
        #     break
        func, args, kargs = tasks.get()
        try:
            func(*args, **kargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            tasks.task_done()


def wait_delay(d):
    print('sleeping for (%d)sec' % d)
    time.sleep(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tasks = Queue()

    for d in range(1,5):
        tasks.put((wait_delay, (d,), {}))

    threadpool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
    # threadpool.map_async(threadworker, [tasks])
    threadpool.map(threadworker, [tasks]) # blocking...
    tasks.join()
```

Comment: Wht is `randrange`?

Comment: randrange is irrelevant here, so I've simplified my script

Comment: Does `while True:` ever exit?

Comment: Queue.get() is blocking it will just sit there and wait for something to get. Maybe specify a timeout and handle the exception by breaking out of the while. https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get

Comment: oh, too easy,  works with `break` in the `finally`.  thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue.get() is blocking it will just sit there and wait for something to get. Specify a timeout and handle the exception by breaking out of the while loop.

```
from queue import Queue,Empty
def threadworker(tasks):
    while True:
        # try:
        #     func, args, kargs = tasks.get(block=False)
        # except Empty:
        #     break
        try:
            func, args, kargs = tasks.get(timeout=5)
        except Empty:
            break
        try:
            func(*args, **kargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            tasks.task_done()
```